# Remove class that has been added by parent theme

Tags: php, functions, filters

My parent theme generates the following class in `body`: `style-cupcake`. I don't want that. The best way to get rid of this is by adding my own functions in a `functions.php` file in my child theme, right?

I tried this (a solution I found on WPSE) but it does not seem to work. "custom background" is removed, but style-cupcake persists.

```
<?php

function my_body_class( $wp_classes, $extra_classes )
{
    // List of the only WP generated classes that are not allowed
    $blacklist = array('custom-background', 'style-cupcake');
    // Blacklist result: (uncomment if you want to blacklist classes)
    $wp_classes = array_diff( $wp_classes, $blacklist );

    // Add the extra classes back untouched
    return array_merge( $wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes );
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 10, 2 );

?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a later priority, eg. 11 instead of 10?

Comment: @toscho I had not. So, basically what does is: all functions are called with a priority (quickest being 1) and a latter can overwrite a former? Thank you, it works! Please provide your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply a filter to the same content another function has filtered, change the *priority* argument (which should have been named _execution_order_) to a higher number.

So …

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 11, 2 );
```

… will make sure `my_body_class()` will be called after `another_body_class()` that has been registered with 10:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'another_body_class', 10, 2 );
```

Also note the *priority* argument will be used as an array key. It doesn’t have to be a number, just a valid key.

```
// this works!
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 'very late please', 2 );
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```