# How to edit classes in body tag?

Tags: functions, filters, child-theme

I'm trying to edit classes in the body tag for custom post types so I can display the pages full width using the WooThemes Canvas built in full width class - instead of overriding it.

By default it seems the body class is set to 'two-col-right' and 'two-col-right-1080' for custom post types, I need them to be 'one-col' and 'one-col-1080'

Simple you would think, but it seems there is no way to edit a class, only a way to filter it out and add a new one?

It does add the 2 classes now but the old ones are not filtered out. can anyone see any issues with my code or is there an easier way to do this? thanks

[this WordPress Answers post is very similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95798/remove-class-that-has-been-added-by-parent-theme?rq=1)

The code so far is:

```
//*** make Services full col ***/
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_post_full_width', 'very late please', 2 );
function custom_post_full_width( $wp_classes, $extra_classes ) {
if ( is_archive('services') OR is_singular('services') ) {

// List of the only WP generated classes that are not allowed
$blacklist = array('two-col-right', 'two-col-right-1080');
// Blacklist result
$wp_classes = array_diff( $wp_classes, $blacklist );
// Extra classes to add
$extra_classes = array('one-col','one-col-1080');
}

// Add the extra classes back untouched
return array_merge( $wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes );
}
```

Not working though :(

i'm using funcions.php with a child theme of Canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
//*** make Services full col ***/
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_post_full_width', 999, 2 );
function custom_post_full_width( $wp_classes, $class ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('services') OR is_singular('services') ) {

        // List of the only WP generated classes that are not allowed
        $blacklist = array('two-col-right', 'two-col-right-1080');

        // Blacklist result
        $wp_classes = array_diff( $wp_classes, $blacklist );

        // Extra classes to add
        $wp_classes = array_merge( $wp_classes, array('one-col','one-col-1080') );

    }

    // Add the extra classes back untouched
    return $wp_classes;
}
```

1. use [is_post_type_archive( $post_type )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

Comment: amazing, thanks Ravs, now it is working perfectly and I'll be able to sleep again at night, thanks :)